# open-source web mapp

Tags: web-mapping, open-source-gis, server

What is the most easy way for a noob guy in coding to create interactive web-maps ?
In GIS field I've worked with QGIS as open-source software, but keept my project on desktop.
In my research I've found this combination for web maps-- Geoserver+Leaflet. 
Right now I'm studying Geoserver's documentation.
Any tutorials to recomend ?

Comment: This is too broad a question to be successfully answered on this site.